# Fill input with jquery variable (Input receive html code)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to open an external page in the DOM.

But I am trying to fetch all the child tags from a div and save it to the javascript variable and then print the variable in the input value

I need to save in the input all html content of the div and the child tags:

```
     <form method="POST" action="test.php">
                <input id="content" type="text" name="content" value="<script>document.write(content)</script>"> 
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>


        <div id="mydiv"></div>// here load external page


        <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#mydiv").load("index.html"); // load external page in Dom

            var content = $(this).closest('#div1'); 
            /* find all parents tags e content of div id="div1" 
            (This is inside the external index.html file) */

        });

        </script>
```

I'm not getting it, I do not know where I'm going wrong in the code above

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//try like below
 <form method="POST" action="test.php">
            <input id="content" type="text" name="content" value=""> 
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


    <div id="mydiv"></div>// here load external page


    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mydiv").load("index.html");
        var loadFile = load("index.html"); 
        var content = $(loadFile).find('#div1').html();
        $('#content').val(content);

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `callback` function to view/explore the loaded contents using [**$.fn.load**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mydiv").load("index.html", function(data){
        // assuming #div1 is inside "index.html"
        var content = $(data).find("#div1");
    });
});
```